# centering search controller vertically iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I added UISearchController programmatically with code

```
 let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Введіть значення для пошуку"
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true

}
```

But it seems that it is not centered vertically. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Does ```searchController.searchBar.center = CGPoint(x: searchController.searchBar.center.x, y: searchController.searchBar.superview?.center.y ?? searchController.searchBar.center.y)``` help?

Comment: no(((( still the same

Comment: Can you provide more context. How is your navigationItem created and placed?

Comment: it is created with code I listed. and I think it is placed automatically

Answer (score 1):

Connected SearchController to TableView instead of NavigationItem

tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in iOS. For some reason at least on iOS 15 searchbar textfield frame has initial value of y = 1 but after you click on the field and then leave this field it will go to y = 8. Fixing the initial frame manually in viewDidLayoutSubviews solved this problem in my case:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.frame.origin.y = 8
}
```